# Concatenation of strings within a loop and Disallowed exception thrown: java.lang.Exception

Tags: java

In the following code

```
for (UserSelection userSelection : filterList) {
                    String filterName = checkForDataHolder(userSelection
                            .getCriteriaName());
                    csvRow.append(filterName + ":");
                    List<String> list = userSelection.getCriteriaValues();
                    String filterval = "";
                    csvRow.append(DATA_DELIMITER);
                    for (String value : list) {

                        filterval += checkForDataHolder(value) + ", ";
                    }
                    if (filterval.indexOf(",") != -1) {
                        filterval = filterval.substring(0, filterval
                                .lastIndexOf(","));
                    }
                    csvRow.append(DATA_HOLDER + filterval + DATA_HOLDER);
                    csvRow.append(NEW_LINE);

                }
```

This line `filterval += checkForDataHolder(value) + ", ";`

causes Concatenation of strings within a loop which creates a StringBuffer for each concatenation. When placed in a loop, this can result in the creation and collection of large numbers of temporary objects.
**How do I create a StringBuffer before entering the loop, and append to it within the loop ?**

Also in the following code

```
final StringBuffer csvRow = new StringBuffer();
        csvRow.append(NEW_LINE);
        csvRow.append(" ");
```

**I want to Replace the string literal with a character literal to improve performance**

consider the following code

```
public void writeHeader(List<String> headerColList) throws IOException {
        this.header = headerColList;
        String val;
        try {
            final StringBuffer csvRow = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    csvRow.append(DATA_DELIMITER);
                }
                val = checkForDataHolder(headerColList.get((i)));
                if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(val)) {
                    csvRow.append(DATA_HOLDER + val + DATA_HOLDER);
                }
            }
            if(!isHeaderProcessed) {
                if(this.header != null) {
                    writer.write(csvRow.toString());
                        writer.write(NEW_LINE);
                    }
                    isHeaderProcessed = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
```

**I want to consider catching a more specific class of exception (one or more subclasses of Exception).which is the best option here ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (String value : list) {

                    filterval += checkForDataHolder(value) + ", ";
                }

if (filterval.indexOf(",") != -1) {
                        filterval = filterval.substring(0, filterval
                                .lastIndexOf(","));
                    }
```

What's going on here? seems to be a very inefficient of taking off the trailing space. Maybe this is faster:

```
bool Appended = false;
for (String value : list) {
                    if(Appended) { filterval += " ";}
                    filterval += checkForDataHolder(value) + ",";
                    Appended = true;
                }
```

Things like scanning along a string are more time consuming than using " " instead of ' '.

The exception is really your choice. Are you expecting  more than memory allocation errors?

Comment: Not really , I just want to know if just throwing IOException  is worh in this case

Comment: did the suggestion help with performance? often these things are negligible, but it depends on size of string an how often a function is called. Don't worry about throwing the exception, it's safer than hoping the code went right. Just make sure to catch the error elsewhere and print a useful (for the user) message  before exiting

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create a StringBuffer before entering the loop, and append to it within the loop?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for ..... { }
String filterval = sb.toString();
```

> I want to Replace the string literal with a character literal to improve performance?

So what keeps you from writing `' '` instead of  `" "`? By the way, it wouldn't probably improve performance in any noticeably way. In the case of NEW_LINE, I am not sure if this is a character or a string constant, but note it may be a string constant with a length greater 1, like "\r\n".

> I want to consider catching a more specific class of exception (one or more subclasses of Exception).which is the best option here ?

The best option is to catch the exceptions that may actually occur and that you can handle.